# import mongo ISODate function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to do a query between dates. In compass I can do the query without any problem using the native function `ISODate()`. But when trying in my code I can't import that function, and `new Date()` is not warking.

Documents as example:

```
let trxs = [{
    _id:612e112f7a7eaa7a5c1fd0d3
    created:2021-09-31T11:23:25.184+00:00
    amount:19.98
    user:"612e112f7a7eaa7a5c1fd0d1"
    type:"deposit"
  },
  {
    _id:612e112f7a7eaa7a5c1fd0d6
    created:2021-09-31T11:23:25.184+00:00
    amount:10
    user:"612e112f7a7eaa7a5c1fd0d4"
    type:"deposit"
  }
]
```

Query

```
let trxs = await Transaction.aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            type: req.query.type,
            $and: [
              {
                created:
                {
                  $gt: new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0))
                },
              },
              {
                created:
                {
                  $lt:new Date(new Date().setHours(23, 59, 59))
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }, {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            amount: {
              $sum: '$amount'
            }
          }
        }
      ]);
```

//More info:

```
console.log(new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0))) // 2021-08-31T22:00:00.953Z
console.log(new Date(new Date().setHours(23, 59, 59))) // 2021-09-01T21:59:59.952Z
```

//Error
 `ReferenceError: amount is not defined`

I tried to import ISODate function but I don't find the way to do it.

Comment: Which line is giving you that error?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library. There is no need for `$and: []`

```
{
   $match: {
     type: req.query.type,
     created: {
       $gt: moment().startOf('day').toDate(),
       $lt: moment().endOf('day').toDate(),
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I read here why shouldn't use moment.js https://inventi.studio/en/blog/why-you-shouldnt-use-moment-js 

The next one looks like a better option https://www.npmjs.com/package/dayjs

Here are some other alternatives https://medium.com/swlh/best-moment-js-alternatives-5dfa6861a1eb

Comment: @ferpalma21.eth When you still use the `mongo` legacy shell, then the new libraries do not work. `mongo` and `mongosh` are quite different, usually you cannot simply exchange them. But yes, in mongosh or Node.js you should use one of the modern libraries, my favorite is [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/?id=luxon) though